Old horror movie about a ship and the end of the world
I am trying to find a movie I saw when I was a kid. I am 38 years old.
It was about a ship (kind of an airplane) and this ship has sections; each section will have something. I remember one section having some kind of insects, and when the people were going over each section, they would release what was there, so they released the insects into the world.
The last section of the ship had, in ice, some kind of creature and the movie made a big deal of it, like the existence of it shouldn't be possible and it was the end of the world.

Is the "ship" a spaceship or an ocean-going vessel?

How those creatures and insects look like?

@Organic Marble I think it was a spaceship, I dont remember the ocean on the movie.

@Yaroslav Kornachevskyi I dont remember exactly but they werent big, they moved in swarms

Do you remember anything else? Black and white, or color? Language (English, German, etc.)? Sound like a small cast...any recognisable faces?

@DavidLee do not put a space in user names ... the users do not get an alert if a space is present

@OrganicMarble I think it was a spaceship, I dont remember the ocean on the movie.

@YaroslavKornachevskyi I dont remember exactly but they werent big, they moved in swarms

@DavidLee yes, you already answered above. Were they different in different sections? Can you add some description of men on that ship? Were they soldiers? Astronauts? What was movie timeframe? Our time, some future?

@ArlettaS I would like to say Black and White, but for some reason I remember a light green color so I am not 100% could be I was imagining too, I was a kid, this was on local television, and they would show it dubbed into Spanish

@YaroslavKornachevskyi sorry, because of the comment from jsotola I made the comment again without spaces in the user names. I dont remember soldiers nor Astronauts, I think there were scientists, the "ship" was sealed shut, and they went section by section, and there was this feeling that they shouldnt do it, each section was kind of worst than the last, the "monster" being the last. I remember the insects because it felt like the plagues from the bible. It was in our time, not the future, they will show buildings outside where the insects were swarming.

@DavidLee so scientists were on that "ship" during the whole movie or they somehow entered it? Were there any other people? Can you also describe those sections?

@YaroslavKornachevskyi they were outside and the ship was sealed shut, so they opened each section one by one going to "head" of the ship, I cant remember more people nor the other sections, only the more impactful ones, the insect and the "monster", I can say there werent a lot of sections.

@DavidLee was the origin of the "ship" alien?

@YaroslavKornachevskyi It didnt look alien, looked "normal" from earth, but well its an old movie, so they wouldnt invest more in the ship, it felt it was something secondary, the suspense generated was more about "dont open", "opens it anyway", "what is inside"

It is possible the movie was Quatermass and the PIt or Five Million Years to Earth (1967), based on the British television serial Quatermass and the Pit 22 December 1958 to 26 Janaury 1959.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_and_the_Pit_(film)#Home_media_release
The original tv serial was probably black and white & has been released on home video, DVD and Blu-Ray.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_and_the_Pit
The 1967 movie was in glorious "dying" color and has been released on DVD and Blu-ray.
A spaceship millions of years old is found buried underneath London. Scientists investigate. There are dead insect like aliens aboard, and some sort of memory recording is played showing insect like aliens fighting, which may have been in black and white in contrast to the rest of the movie.  And at the end a "Giant Monster" - sort of - does menace London.  The insect like aliens are green.
And it is generally considered a classic science fiction film, so is worth seeing even if it isn't the one you remember.

Just watched the movie, what a good movie, but its not it, this one looks more new I would say, and the final monster is not that one, its more like a big foot trapped in ice and the ice is melting.
